# error on opening a csv file using a jet oledb connection in excel vba

Tags: vba, oledb, oledbconnection

First time I'm using stackoverflow so here goes...

I've been getting errors intermittently when I try to run a macro in excel which I use for pulling in data from a CSV file. The error normally goes away if I start a fresh session, but this time it's been particularly persistant. It basically errors on the .Open line below, giving me a "Run-time error '2147467259' (80004005) Unspecified error":

```
Public Sub LoadFile()

file_path = Range("FlatFileLocation")

Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & file_path & "; Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)"";"

oConn.Open strcon

.....
```

Other info:

1) the file I'm trying to access is not open by another user

2) I close my connections at the end of the sub. also, i just tried restarting my machine and the error happened the first time I tried running the file

3) When I open my session up without any of my existing addins it seems to work. Is there any way of checking whether there is some sort of addin conflict going on?

There were other posts that suggest using [CSVReader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). Questions I have before trying this route are:

1) can I use this CSVReader across multiple user machines? The problem I would have here is needing to install it on a number of machines. I might be able to put a file on a shared drive however.

2) Can I query the resultant file with a SQL string? At the moment I use something like this:

```
....
strsql = "SELECT * FROM ( " & strsql & " ) WHERE ( ABS(PrevRisk) + ABS(CurrRisk) >= " & RiskThreshold & " ) ;"
Set oResult = New ADODB.Recordset
oResult.Open strsql, oConn
....
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: CSVReader io written in C#. If you want to use it from VBA, you would have to expose it as a COM object. As far as querying with SQL, CSVReader doesn't support SQL.

Comment: thanks for the response - I guess that rules it out for my purposes. Is there another way of querying data in a CSV file from excel? I've heard that it might be a good idea to convert it into an MDB file first?

Comment: Does this have to be within the Excel environment? You could import from CVS and export to an Excel file under WSH (save a file with the `.vbs` extension and run it).

Comment: If you think it's an add-in problem, you can disable add-ins one at a time from the VBA IDE window, `Add-Ins -> Add-In Manager...`

Comment: No idea if this will help or not, but maybe try writing a [`schema.ini`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file -- (example [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;149090)).